# How to disable a selectpicker

Tags: javascript, html, forms, css

When a certain value is put into a form, the selectpicker have to be disabled.

**This is the selectpicker:**

```
 <input type="text" name="tipologia" id="tipologia"/>

<select class="selectpicker" name="sottocon" id="sottocon_%idTipoScadenza%" data-live-search="true"
   autofocus>
            </select>
```

**This is the event**

```
TipologieX();
$("#tipologia").on('input', function (e) {
    TipologieX();
});


function TipologieX() {
    var tipo = document.getElementById("tipologia").value;

if (tipo == 0) {
        document.getElementById("tipoanagrafico").value = "C";
        document.getElementById("tipoanagrafico").readOnly = true;

    } else if (tipo == 1) {
        document.getElementById("tipoanagrafico").value = "";
        document.getElementById("tipoanagrafico").readOnly = false;
        document.getElementById("#ssottoconto_%idTipoScadenza%").attr("disabled", true);
        document.getElementById("#sottocon_%idTipoScadenza%").readOnly = true;
        document.getElementById("#sottocon_%idTipoScadenza%").prop("disabled", true);

    }
```

The selectpicker being abled/disabled depends on the value of the input "tipologia".

Non of these works, can someone help?

Comment: selectpicker? Is that some sort of 3rd party library? I see a select element,  In your code you are using invalid methods. `prop()` and `attr()` are not part of JavaScript.

Comment: It should just be `document.getElementById("theId").disabled = true;`

Comment: these where "tests" i found online

Comment: It still isn't working, I don't know why, but thanks..

Comment: Look in the developer console for errors, what do you see? Are you using jQuery because it is not tagged jQuery and you have jQuery code in it? Are you sure it is going into the if/else like you expect. console.log() is your friend.

Comment: Ok just a few mins and I'll update you

Comment: You don't have element with id `tipoanagrafico` in your html so all the code that handles it doesn't really make much sense right now. Apart from the obvious mistakes, what are you trying to achieve with this? And are you aware of the fact that you are using jQuery functions?  Are you including jQuery library in your code?

Comment: As long as you don't provide a _working_ code snippet that reproduce the issue described, any answer will be a guess. Update your question.

Comment: Ok so.. Yes I'm aware of that, tried the console.log() and it showed this message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null
    at TipologieX"

Comment: And "tipoanagrafico" is another input which values change when the values of "tipologia" changes.. Just like the selectpicker should do, it's there to show that when the value is 0 the selectpicker is enabled but when it's 1 it is disabled.. Sorry for the bad english and the misunderstanding..

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("#sottocon_%idTipoScadenza%").disabled = true
```

Keep in mind that your `input#tipologia` value is of type `String`. So if you want to compare values, you need to coerce types of values:

```
if (tipo === String(0)) {
  // blah blah
}
```